# How to make comma seperated data for cksum

Tags: linux

How to make comma seperated data for cksum

find hadoop-3.0.0 -type f | xargs cksum

2840095922 951 hadoop-3.0.0/etc/hadoop/mapred-env.cmd

I have to make the result set as comma seperated like below
2840095922,951,hadoop-3.0.0/etc/hadoop/mapred-env.cmd

How to do it
Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Abu

Answer (score 0):

First, without external tools.

```
IFS=$'\n'; for line in `find hadoop-3.0.0 -type f | xargs cksum`; do echo ${line// /,}; done
```

Second, used sed tool.

```
find hadoop-3.0.0/ -type f | xargs cksum | sed 's/ /,/g'
```